# How to set and use direct files folder path in a multisite installation

Tags: 8, files, multi-sites, .htaccess

Drupal 8 multisite install where

1. First site is on a subdomain one.example.com
2. Second site is in a subfolder one.example.com/two

**How can files folder for both sites to be accessible via URL/files and not URL/sites/domain/files**

- current: one.example.com/sites/one.example.com/files
- desired: one.example.com/files
- current: one.example.com/two/sites/two/files
- desired: one.example.com/two/files

I tried several variants listed here https://www.drupal.org/node/53705 and put them at following locations, but nothing worked.

1. Drupal8/.htaccess
2. Drupal8/files/.htaccess
3. Drupal8/sites/two/files/.htaccess

Setup information is provided below

---

Filesystem setup

```
--Drupal8
  --index.php
  --one.example.com (sym link ln -s . one.example.com)
  --two (sym link ln -s . two) Not required in D8, but could not get the subfolder site to work without it.
  --sites
    --default (sym links to one.example.com)
    --one.example.com
      --settings.php, services.yml
      --files, modules,etc
    --two
      --settings.php, services.yml
      --files, modules,etc
```

Sites.php

```
$sites = [];
$sites['one.example.com'] = 'one.example.com';
$sites['one.example.com.two'] = 'two';
```

Apache setup : One virtual host for one.example.com

Comment: What did you actually put in /.htaccess that did not work? We use something like:

      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(foo\.bar\.com
      RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ sites/foo/files/$1 [NC,L]

Comment: I tried `RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ /sites/%{HTTP_HOST}/files/$1 [L, R] and RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/%{HTTP_HOST}/files/$1 [L, R]` Which .htaccess file are you adding this to?

Comment: The root .htaccess in the site directory, where Drupal is installed. Note, this is an edit of the .htaccess provided by Drupal. Does HTTP_HOST match the multisite directory name in every case on this site?

Comment: The subdomain site matches the HTTP_HOST, but sub folder does not, as it will be more cryptic (one.example.com.two) and won't match HTTP_HOST anyways. I tried your suggestion to see if at least the  subdomain site's files would work, but it did not.

Comment: I also tried to hardcode path on subdomain `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^one\.example\.com$ [NC] RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ sites/one.example.com/files/$1 [NC,L]` this did not work

Comment: Do I need to make a change in public file system path after the rewrite rule from sites/one.example.com/files to files?

Comment: I got subdomain file to work, by adding the the rule above the rule that directs everything to index.php in Drupal's root .htaccess

Comment: Oh, I thought that was obvious. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In /.htaccess, above other rewrite rules, use something like this example for foo.bar.com:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.bar\.com
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ sites/foo.bar.com/files/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: This works on the site (one) which is on subdomain, but not for the site (two) which is in a subfolder

Comment: This worked, as we'll need separate rule for sub folder
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /two/
  RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ sites/two/files/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/two/
  RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ sites/%{HTTP_HOST}/files/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Since in this case one site is on subdomain the other on subfolder, single rule as mentioned by @cilefen is not sufficient. So we need to make two rules in this case, one for the subfolder site and other for the subdomain site. The subfolder site rule is hardcoded as we can't generalize it.

The rewrite rules need to be added to Drupal core's .htaccess (i.e one next to index.php). This will also require changes to .htaccess on every Drupal upgrade as the stock file won't have these rules.

```
  # Subfolder site
  # match subfolder site url path and amend its file path
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /two/files/
  RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ sites/two/files/$1 [L]

  # Subdomain site
  # if the url path matches subfolder site skip this rule
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/two/files/
  RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ sites/%{HTTP_HOST}/files/$1 [L]
```

These rules need to be above the following, else they won't work

```
  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Thanks to @cilefen for putting me on the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

No need for any server config. You can do this by setting `$settings['file_public_path'] = 'files';` in both your sites `settings.php` files.

See [`default.settings.php`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!default!default.settings.php/8.2.x) (click "View source")

> ```
> /**
>  * Public file path:
>  *
>  * A local file system path where public files will be stored. This directory
>  * must exist and be writable by Drupal. This directory must be relative to
>  * the Drupal installation directory and be accessible over the web.
>  */
>
> # $settings['file_public_path'] = 'sites/default/files';
> ```